# Stop stars overlapping javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mobile

So i am really confused on this one.

[image]

As you can see in developer tools on mobile everything looks fine with the layout but when i deploy a live version the stars overlap. I firstly thought this could be a safari based issue or device issue of some sort. But it is the same in chrome and on any mobile device. On desktops it is fine. I thought this could also be how the stars are being dynamically loaded onto the page so i changed the positioning of the script tags to place them at the end of the body but to still no avail.

Here is the output once live

[image]

MARKUP:

```
@* Brands *@
<section class="container container12 mb-5" id="indexBrands">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center my-3">
            <p class="h2">Featured Brands</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row p-xs-2">

        <div class="col m-2 d-flex justify-content-center" style="border:1px solid black">
            <div class="row flex-column h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <a class="d-flex justify-content-center" href="/info/korniche"><img class="img-fluid m-2 p-1" data-src="@Model.BaseUrl/filestore/pageimages/Sterlingbuild-homepage/brands/area/korniche.jpg" alt="Korniche flat glass lanterns" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <p class="text-center lowerText p-1">Sleek and elegant glass roof lanterns ideal for elevating your flat roof extensions.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end">
                    <div class="korniche-rating text-center mb-3"></div>
                    <a class="align-self-center mb-3 ml-2" href="/info/korniche" id="signaturetCount"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Force next columns to break to new line at xs breakpoint and down -->
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-block d-sm-none"></div>

        <div class="col m-2 d-flex justify-content-center" style="border:1px solid black">
            <div class="row flex-column h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <a class="d-flex justify-content-center" href="~/info/eco-plus-flat-roof-lights"><img class="img-fluid m-2 p-1" data-src="@Model.BaseUrl/filestore/pageimages/Sterlingbuild-homepage/brands/area/eco-plus.jpg" alt="ECO+ Flat Glass Rooflights" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <p class="text-center lowerText p-1">Eco friendly pitched and flat roof windows designed for adding natural light with minimum fuss.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end">
                    <div class="eco-rating text-center mb-3"></div>
                    <a class="align-self-center mb-3 ml-2" href="/info/eco-plus-flat-roof-lights" id="ecoCount"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Force next columns to break to new line at xs breakpoint and down-->
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-block d-sm-none"></div>

        <div class="col m-2 d-flex justify-content-center" style="border:1px solid black">
            <div class="row flex-column h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <a class="d-flex justify-content-center" href="~/info/signature"><img class="img-fluid m-2 p-1" data-src="@Model.BaseUrl/filestore/pageimages/Sterlingbuild-homepage/brands/area/signature.jpg" alt="Signature rooflights" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <p class="text-center lowerText p-1">Fully certified, UK-manufactured rooflights. The number one choice for bespoke flat roof glazing solutions.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end">
                    <div class="signature-rating text-center mb-3"></div>
                    <a class="align-self-center mb-3 ml-2" href="/info/signature" id="signaturetCount"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Force next columns to break to new line at xs breakpoint and down -->
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-sm-block"></div>

        <!-- Force next columns to break to new line at xs breakpoint and down -->
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-block d-sm-none"></div>

        <div class="col m-2 d-flex justify-content-center" style="border:1px solid black">
            <div class="row flex-column h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <a class="d-flex justify-content-center" href="~/info/velux"><img class="img-fluid m-2 p-1" data-src="@Model.BaseUrl/filestore/pageimages/Sterlingbuild-homepage/brands/area/velux.jpg" alt="VELUX Pitched and flat roof windows" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <p class="text-center lowerText p-1">World renowned pitched roof windows built for creating a brighter and healthier indoor climate.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end">
                    <div class="velux-rating text-center mb-3"></div>
                    <a class="align-self-center mb-3 ml-2" href="/info/velux" id="veluxCount"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Force next columns to break to new line at xs breakpoint and down -->
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-block d-sm-none"></div>

        <div class="col m-2 d-flex justify-content-center" style="border:1px solid black">
            <div class="row flex-column h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <a class="d-flex justify-content-center" href="~/info/rooflite"><img class="img-fluid m-2 p-1" data-src="@Model.BaseUrl/filestore/pageimages/Sterlingbuild-homepage/brands/area/rooflite.jpg" alt="Rooflight roof windows" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <p class="text-center lowerText p-1">Pitched roof windows guaranteed to brighten up your loft conversion without breaking the bank.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end">
                    <div class="rooflight-rating text-center mb-3"></div>
                    <a class="align-self-center mb-3 ml-2" href="/info/rooflite" id="rooflightCount"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Force next columns to break to new line at xs breakpoint and down -->
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-block d-sm-none"></div>

        <div class="col m-2 d-flex justify-content-center" style="border:1px solid black">
            <div class="row flex-column h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <a class="d-flex justify-content-center" href="~/info/lightway"><img class="img-fluid m-2 p-1" data-src="@Model.BaseUrl/filestore/pageimages/Sterlingbuild-homepage/brands/area/lightway.jpg" alt="Lightway sun tunnels" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <p class="text-center lowerText p-1">Precision engineered Crystal sun tunnels perfect for introducing daylight into the darker areas of a property.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end">
                    <div class="lightway-rating text-center mb-3"></div>
                    <a class="align-self-center mb-3 ml-2" href="/info/lightway" id="lightwayCount"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

   <script src="~/Content/JS/getStarRating.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Content/JS/insertStars.js"></script>
```

getStarRating.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.get("/api/feefo/132",
    function (data) {
        kornicheRating(data.Rating);
    });

$.get("/api/feefo/10",
    function (data) {
        ecoRating(data.Rating);
    });

$.get("/api/feefo/108",
    function (data) {
        signatureRating(4.0);
    });

$.get("/api/feefo/7",
    function (data) {
        veluxRating(data.Rating);
    });

$.get("/api/feefo/5",
    function (data) {
        rooflightRating(data.Rating);
    });

$.get("/api/feefo/74",
    function (data) {
        lightwayRating(data.Rating);
    });

 });
```

insertStars.js:

```
function kornicheRating(rating) {
    $(".korniche-rating").starRating({
        starSize: 30,
        readOnly: true,
        initialRating: rating,
    });
}

function ecoRating(rating) {
    $(".eco-rating").starRating({
        starSize: 30,
        readOnly: true,
        initialRating: rating,
    });
}

function signatureRating(rating) {
    $(".signature-rating").starRating({
        starSize: 30,
        readOnly: true,
        initialRating: rating,
    });
}

function veluxRating(rating) {
    $(".velux-rating").starRating({
        starSize: 30,
        readOnly: true,
        initialRating: rating,
    });
}

function rooflightRating(rating) {
    $(".rooflight-rating").starRating({
        starSize: 30,
        readOnly: true,
        initialRating: rating,
    });
}

function lightwayRating(rating) {
    $(".lightway-rating").starRating({
        starSize: 30,
        readOnly: true,
        initialRating: rating,
    });
}
```

Comment: I’d start by hooking up a mobile to your desktop computer via USB, so that you can do some proper remote debugging. https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-remote-debug-websites-on-android-devices-with-chrome-e0afc661a8e8

Comment: Have you a link for iOS

Comment: https://medium.com/@nikoloza/how-to-debug-remote-ios-device-using-chrome-devtools-f44d697003a7